# Proper HTML Form Validation with JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

here's simple  html form validated with JavaScript , it show error message when the required fields are empty and when username is short(not satisfy the required length)..but form is sending data when submit button is clicked even if errors are displayed....how can i properly validate this form?

here's the code

```js
let form = document.getElementById("signUp");
let uname = document.querySelector("#userName");
let uemail = document.querySelector("#userEmail");

const showError = (input, message) => {
  // get the form-field element
  const formField = input.parentElement;

  // show the error message
  const error = formField.querySelector('small');
  error.textContent = message;
};

const showSuccess = (input) => {
  // get the form-field element
  const formField = input.parentElement;

  // hide the error message
  const error = formField.querySelector('small');
  error.textContent = '';
}
const validateForm = () => {
  if (uname.value.trim() == "") {
    showError(uname, "name is empty");
    return false;
  } else {
    showSuccess(uname);
  }
  if (uemail.value.trim() == "") {
    showError(uemail, "email is empty");
    return false;
  } else {
    showSuccess(uemail);
  }
  return true;
}

const checkUsername = () => {
  const username = uname.value.trim();
  if (username.length < 3) {
    showError(uname, 'Username must be atleast 4 characters')
    return false;
  } else {
    showSuccess(uname);
  }
  return true;
}


form.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  switch (event.target.id) {
    case 'userName':
      checkUsername();
      break;
  }
});
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  if (!validateForm()) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Validation</h2>

<form id="signUp" name="myForm">
  <div>
    Name: <input type="text" name="uname" id="userName">
    <small id="showMessage" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br> Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="userEmail">
    <small id="showMessage" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">sign up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Start with valid HTML. You're missing a `</div>`

Comment: Your code appears to be working as expected. The form doesn't submit if it is invalid. What is the actual problem?

Comment: @Phil it should stop submit when username does not satisfy the required length

Comment: You need to call `checkUsername()` within `validateForm()`... at the end you could simply add `return checkUsername()` instead of `return true`

Comment: @Phil it does not work can u provide a working demo?

Comment: How **exactly** does it _"not work"_? Please update the code in your question to match anything new you're trying

Comment: Working demo using exactly the two changes I proposed ~ https://jsfiddle.net/bry12os3/

Comment: So why did you say it didn't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249464/discussion-between-willy-and-phil).